# What is transpoil?

Tags: plot-explanation, preacher

I just finished *Preacher* season 3 and right in the first episode (Angelville) Madame L'Angell request the Preacher something called "transpoil".

I tried googling but couldn't find any mention of this anywhere, except for some product pages for waste oil extraction pumps... It's also not even mentioned for the rest of the season.

So what is this transpoil she asks for? Is there any explanation in the comics, is it something real world psychics / mystics use, or is it a redneck name for something?

Comment: ["The compound was ‘transpoil’, which I guess is a portmanteau of transportation and oil." / "Maybe. However, in French, Transpoil is something that makes you laugh out loud or creates extreme humour."](https://tvline.com/2018/06/24/preacher-season-3-episode-1-premiere-recap-tulip-lives/)

Comment: @BCdotWEB I thought about the first one but I was wondering if there's anything in the source material, or if it's something known in the mystical circles in real life

Answer (score 1):

Transpoil is a potion (liquid with magical attributes) used as part of resurrection ritual.

Some sources to support this claim: (emphasis mine)

> She agrees and sends Jesse and Cassidy out to procure various items required to perform the **resurrection ritual**

<sup>[source](http://www.museled.com/2018/07/preacher-s03e01-angelville-recap.html)</sup>

---

> Jody takes Jesse to a motel owned by the Boyd's and the former fights his way into stealing a **vile** of transpoil

---

> Gran'ma gives Tulip a **drop of transpoil**.

<sup>[source](https://preacher.fandom.com/wiki/Angelville_(episode))</sup>

---

> With the help of the **transpoil**, Boo Berry cereal, and Joni Mitchell, Gran’ma starts **coaxing Tulip back to the land of the living**

<sup>[source](https://monkeysfightingrobots.co/preacher-feature-angelville/)</sup>

As for the question "is it something real world psychics" well it's not. There isn't (yet?) any way to resurrect dead people.

Answer (score -1):

I believe it is used as lube to pull the soul thru, back from purgatory.

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Movies & TV Stack Exchange! While I think your answer is helpful, it might be worth editing it to better explain that perhaps the real-world definition is being applied to supernatural action.  (That is, if I understand your answer correctly?!)

Comment: if you could [edit] your answer to add some references to back what you're saying it would be great! Is that something from another movie / book or does it come from some real life cult / religion?

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure but I figure out it could be a portmanteau word of transportation and oil. Because it is supposed to be used to call spirit back.